# QR Code Types that default mobile camera can recognise

Tags: android, qr-code

I am trying to build an android application to construct a QR code that can be scanned by default camera's of mobile.

For example, facebook build [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links/#qr_codes) type of QR codes that can be scanned by default camera's of mobile. So, I started searching what are the standard formats/types of QR codes that mobile default camera's can recognise but didn't find any specific information on it. I have already tried some open source library's based on the [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) library and the qr codes generated by these library's do recognised by the default camera's, but didn't find any informations about the formats/types of QR codes they are generating.

So my question is what  are the standard types/formats of QR codes that mobile default camera's recognise? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Each manufacturer has their own version of the camera app which may or may not read QR codes.

Individual apps which use the camera may implement their own QR reader.

Going over the Facebook QR code:

[image: Facebook Messenger QR Code]

While I'm not sure if the Facebook one can be read by ZXing [ed: it works], Facebook can modify their version of ZXing code (or add image processing steps) to make it readable. My guess is that the error correction is high enough that the Facebook Messenger symbol in the middle is just "noise" and the corners are either close enough in design to the position markers for normal QR reader code to understand (or transformed to be so).

For example: If you have control over the reader you can modify your QR code so that it becomes difficult to read without some processing. One example would be make all of the black squares light blue such than a regular QR reader library can't read it. You would then when scanning just change blue to black and then try to process. Another would be to change to background color to not be white reducing the contrast between barcode pixel and background field. Other ideas are possible as QR codes are almost 30 years old (but may not be documented as they are intentionally obscured).